# how to set working the Words gem for my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to use words - interface to WordNet® with cross ruby distribution compatability,for my application. How to set all the essential prerequisites to get this done aprt from installing the gem.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to briefly explain your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to make sure that your OS has a copy of the wordnet data files. If not get it using the command

```
sudo apt-get install wordnet-base
```

Then install the gem `wordnet` and other dependencies if any like `gemcutter` and `tumble`

After this you can use it in your files using  `require 'words'`.

For example :

```
    sample_data = Words.Wordnet.new
```

This must do the work.
Refer the [API](http://rubydoc.info/github/roja/words/master/file/README.markdown) for more details